# Rails - how does method access name fields with no call to a db and no form params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie watching a Lynda.com video about rails 3. The teacher creates a method like this to find a user

```
def name
   "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

He says this will return first name and last name for this user, but I don't understand how this function accesses first_name last_name, since there is no call to a database or no form parameters.

I know that without looking at the whole application it will be impossible for you to explain this, but you may be able to guess what this function might be dependent on.

this is the whole AdminUser model

```
require 'digest/sha1'
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  # To configure a different table name
  # set_table_name("admin_users")

  has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
  has_many :section_edits
  has_many :sections, :through => :section_edits

  attr_accessor :password

  EMAIL_REGEX = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i

  # standard validation methods
  # validates_presence_of :first_name
  # validates_length_of :first_name, :maximum => 25
  # validates_presence_of :last_name
  # validates_length_of :last_name, :maximum => 50
  # validates_presence_of :username
  # validates_length_of :username, :within => 8..25
  # validates_uniqueness_of :username
  # validates_presence_of :email
  # validates_length_of :email, :maximum => 100
  # validates_format_of :email, :with => EMAIL_REGEX
  # validates_confirmation_of :email

  # new "sexy" validations
  validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 25 }
  validates :last_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :username, :length => { :within => 8..25 }, :uniqueness => true
  validates :email, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }, 
    :format => EMAIL_REGEX, :confirmation => true

  # only on create, so other attributes of this user can be changed
  validates_length_of :password, :within => 8..25, :on => :create

  before_save :create_hashed_password
  after_save :clear_password

  scope :named, lambda {|first,last| where(:first_name => first, :last_name => last)}
  scope :sorted, order("admin_users.last_name ASC, admin_users.first_name ASC")

  attr_protected :hashed_password, :salt

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def self.authenticate(username="", password="")
    user = AdminUser.find_by_username(username)
    if user && user.password_match?(password)
      return user
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  # The same password string with the same hash method and salt
  # should always generate the same hashed_password.
  def password_match?(password="")
    hashed_password == AdminUser.hash_with_salt(password, salt)
  end

  def self.make_salt(username="")
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Use #{username} with #{Time.now} to make salt")
  end

  def self.hash_with_salt(password="", salt="")
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Put #{salt} on the #{password}")
  end

  private

  def create_hashed_password
    # Whenever :password has a value hashing is needed
    unless password.blank?
      # always use "self" when assigning values
      self.salt = AdminUser.make_salt(username) if salt.blank?
      self.hashed_password = AdminUser.hash_with_salt(password, salt)
    end
  end

  def clear_password
    # for security and b/c hashing is not needed
    self.password = nil
  end

end
```

Comment: He says it'll *return* a string with the first and last names, not that it'll find a user based on them :)

Comment: but he has to get them from somewhere. Usually he uses a function like find_by_username etc

Comment: Correct. The function is to be used after first_name and last_name are set, either manually or from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method "name" is not finding a user from the database, however the variables inside it (first_name and last_name) are read from the corresponding database table fields. In this case assuming the usual rails conventions are followed you will find a database table called "AdminUsers" and inside it some fields of which one is first_name and another is second_name.

How this all works and why it is so can be found in the Ruby on Rails documentation for [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Comment: thanks, but I'm confused because sometimes he uses functions lik find_by_username etc.  Is there a reason why it needed to use a function like this?

Comment: Have a look at the linked documentation for ActiveRecord. When the teacher uses method names like find_by_username or find_by_last_name these are automatically translated to do a search in the database. Instead of writing SQL code such as "Select * from AdminUsers where username = 'mjmitche" you just do AdminUser.find_by_username('mjmitche')